# RabbitMQ for passing messages between web aplication and twisted backend server

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, twisted

I have a php web application and twisted backend server, thus for communication between two of these I am using RabbitMQ where web application is producer while twisted server is consumer. Following is my code for twisted server.

```
def rabbitMQConsumer():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
    print ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)

    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='hello', no_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()


class Echo(LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        self.setRawMode()
        self._peer = self.transport.getPeer()
        logging.info('Connected Client %s' %self._peer)
        print 'Connected Client', self._peer

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
        logging.info('Lost connection from %s' %self._peer)
        print 'Lost connection from', self._peer

    def rawDataReceived(self, data):
        inputArray = ["%02X"%ord(inp) for inp in data]
        logging.info('Packet received from %s client : %s'%(self._peer,''.join(inputArray)))


t = Thread(target=rabbitMQConsumer)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

I am able to pass messages between web application and twisted server but my problem is that whenever twisted server receives messages from web application I want to forward that message to a particular client connected to server. Whenever callback function is called server sends message to a particular client. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried to apply some routing schema to do that?

Comment: any please explain to me in detail. I am new to twisted and rabbitmq

Comment: The idea is to have per-client queue. You can create `topic` exchange and bind per-client queues to it by routing key like your.meaningful.name.<client name or id>. Then you can start consumer on each client to listen for message on specific queue. There are detailed explanation to do what you want on SO, I clearly remember that I've answered very similar Q before. P.S. Sorry, I'm not a twisted guy so maybe there are some out-of-the-box solution.